# Why is the maximum call stack exceeded in this case?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

First of all: I already know the meaning of this error and I did research on stackoverflow.
I'm a beginner and I don't understand, how this error caused in this particular case and how to fix it.

I get the error, when I try to navigate back to the last view:

```
sap-ui-core.js:976 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at d.a.fireEvent (sap-ui-core.js:976)
    at d.fireNavigate (sap-ui-core.js:573)
    at d.N._backTo (NavContainer.js:6)
    at d.N.back (NavContainer.js:6)
    at constructor.navigation (wiegung.controller.js:106)
    at f.onBeforeShow (wiegung.view.js:17)
    at f.a._handleEvent (sap-ui-core.js:961)
    at d.N._backTo (NavContainer.js:6)
    at d.N.back (NavContainer.js:6)
    at constructor.navigation (wiegung.controller.js:106)
```

So, here is my view:

```
    onBeforeShow : function(oEvent) {
        if (oEvent.isBack){
            this.oController.navigation('back');
        } else {
            this.oController.initData(oEvent.data);
            this.oController.getUiControl();
            this.oController.getDevices();
        }
    },
```

And my controller:

```
navigation : function(oSite, oData) {
        var oApp = sap.ui.getCore().byId("app");
        if (oSite == 'back') {
            oApp.back();
        } else {
            oApp.to(oSite, "slide", oData);
        }
    },
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Certainly no expert here but it looks to me as though `onBeforeShow` navigates back which then calls `onBeforeShow` etc. etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onBeforeShow` calls `navigation` that calls `oApp.back` that calls `oApp._backTo` that calls `_handleEvent` that calls `onBeforeShow` and repeat infinitely.

Comment: How would you fix that?

Comment: Not sure if there is enough information posted for us to be able to fix it. Once you navigate `back()` which page are you landing at? What code do you have there that might cause another navigation to be fired?